# Angular HTTPRequest pipe w/ interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am currently attempting to track upload progress in an angular component.  This component accepts a file and calls a service, which uploads the file to the server.

We currently use an interceptor to inject a header with an auth-token.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (localStorage.getItem('token') != null) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'X-Auth-Token': localStorage.getItem('token')
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: any) => {
                if (error.status === 401) {
                    localStorage.removeItem('token');
                    this.router.navigate(['/public/login']);
                    return of(error);
                }
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
```

If I put a tap() after the map() in here, i can receive the tap notes and log them to the console.

I call the service and attempt to use pipe/tap to get the progress of the upload in my component

```
 this.assetService.upload(formData).pipe(
      map(data => console.log(data)),
      tap(message => console.log(message))
    ).subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });
```

The pipe()/map()/tap() in here is never hit.

Ideally, I'd like to use the tap() in the component to calculate the percentage uploaded and then use it to update a progress bar.

Comment: Did you add `reportProgress: true`: 
 in your HTTP request in assetService.upload function [reportProgress](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#reportProgress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method to or way to use `tap/map/pipe` of RxJs.

```
postImportExportFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<MyObject> {
    this.formData = new FormData();
    this.formData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    const url = 'http://loclahost:4200/myPost/url/to/be/hit';
    return this.http.post(url, this.formData, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'upload': 'true' }), // I used this for change the interceptors accepts and content-type
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
    }).pipe(
      retry(3),
      map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => this.getEventMessage(event, fileToUpload)),
      tap((t: MyObject) => {
        return console.log(`post import export file for );
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<MyObject>(url))
    );
  }
```

The method:

```
getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>, file: File): MyObject{
    const myObject= new MyObject();
    switch (event.type) {
      case HttpEventType.Sent:
        myObject.eventType = UploadEventType.SENT; // This is an enum that help me to add a event type to my object
        myObject.message = `Uploading file "${file.name}" of size ${file.size}.`;
        break;
      case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
        myObject.eventType = UploadEventType.PROGRESS;
        const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        myObject.message = `File "${file.name}" is ${percentDone}% uploaded.`;
        break;
      case HttpEventType.Response:
        console.log(`File "${file.name}" was completely uploaded!`);
        myObject.eventType = UploadEventType.COMPLETED; 
        myObject.message = event;
        break;
      default:
        myObject.eventType = UploadEventType.ERROR;
        myObject.message = `File "${file.name}" surprising upload event: ${event.type}.`;
    }
    return myObject;
  }
```

After receiving the object you can check with if else case what is the event and do your work as per your need.

Here in first part I used method `postImportExportFile` which is post method call and send one header that used to change interceptor value like `headerSettings['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';` and then used observe type: as `events`.

This help us to get `HttpEvent`s and then we change the messages in our side to check and used. the second method you can used directly but I break them and used as my own object.
Hope it will help, Please let me know if you need any further clarification to the code.